# How to force uniq to distinquish between em- and en-dashes?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, uniq

`uniq` (GNU coreutils 8.5) does not seem to distinguish between em- and en-dashes:

$ echo -e "a–b\na—b" | uniq -c

```
  2 a–b
```

Is there any way to force this distinction? I've tried various settings for LC_COLLATE with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked for me

```
echo -e "a–b\na—b" | LC_COLLATE=C uniq -c
      1 a–b
      1 a—b
```

Comment: I see. I was trying various permutations of `LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8` assuming that it _must_ be `utf8` to work. `LC_COLLATE=C` produces the expected results. Cheers!